# Is there any harm in Converting all Customers to Vendors automatically?

Tags: acumatica

I understand that Acumatica treats Customers and Vendors differently, and if you require a customer to also be a Vendor (which is often the case for us) and vice a versa, then you have convert the the Customer to a Vendor (or Vendor to a Customer). We often use the convert to vendor code on git (https://github.com/Acumatica/Acumatica-ExtendToCustomerVendorDuringImport). But my question is, is there any harm or reason not to just convert all vendors to customers and vice a versa to save our users the headache of doing this for each one later on?

Answer (score 0):

There's a general answer to those types of questions. If the operation can be done in the UI by a user then it's assumed there's no harm in doing so. When an operation can't be done in UI due to a validation error it's assumed that making that change would corrupt the data.

Once the operation is confirmed to be working in the UI you can work on an automation script. These can be done with a [Customization Plugin](https://help-2019r1.acumatica.com/(W(2))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=3ef5784b-1602-4a04-b6b9-52b69c79fe91) that runs when the customization project is published.

You should always do the operation using the PXGraph classes of Acumatica. For example, if you need to confirm shipments in a script you create the SOShipmentEntry graph, set the current document of the graph and invoke the confirm shipment action.

Regarding the GitHub project, I don't think it's officially maintained so you'll need to test it. One possible issue you might encounter with conversion is that you can't re-convert the vendor back to a customer once he has started making sales transactions.